# The annotation '...' conflicts with a field on the model

Tags: python, django

I want to write the django equivalent to

```sql
select coalesce(product_id, -1) as product_id from my_table
```

in django. However, trying

```py
MyTable.objects.values(product_id=Coalesce('product_id', -1))
```

gives me the error: `The annotation 'product_id' conflicts with a field on the model.`

This forces me to use a different name, and rename the resulting dicts in python, which is much slower than doing it in the database.

Is there any way to tell django "I know what I'm doing, go on"???

Comment: You can not create a value with the *same* name as the original field.

Comment: That being said, please do *not* use `.values(..)` as a serializer.

Answer (score 3):

Try different name rather than your model attribute,

```
MyTable.objects.values(change_product_id=Coalesce('product_id', -1))
```